# Using Less Generator with Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, less, asset-pipeline

By default when I generate a controller, it generates a corresponding `.css.scss` file.  However, I tend to prefer using less so I'd like rails to generate .less files.

I found this in the `less-rails` gem documentation:

```
config.app_generators.stylesheet_engine :less
```

But even with that inserted into my application.rb, it still creates scss files.  How can I set the app to generate .less by default?

Answer (score 0):

According to [guides.rubyonrails.org](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#controller-specific-assets) seems like you have ensure that `less-rails` gem is installed and is present in `Gemfile`.

Currently not working properly with Sprockets, so if you have `undefined method 'register_preprocessor' for nil:NilClass` 
error, update your Gemfile with:

`gem 'less-rails', github: 'metaskills/less-rails'`

This creates files like `app/assets/stylesheets/some_controller.css.less`